# Magento MSRP price not showing on category

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

i am using magento 2.3.0 i enabled MSRP price from admin setting and from attribute i enable display on product page and showing in attributes list but not showing on product page in area where is it should

Comment: please try: php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: i re-indexed data already not showing

Answer (score 1):

Please verify from below step :

You need to enable MAP feature in

```
Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> Minimum Advertised Price
```

Enable MAP: Yes

than `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: already enabled but stile not showing !